# Read All Lines in a Text File and Add Them C#

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, while-loop

I've been working on this problem for a while and I'm a little stuck.  I have a text file that I need to loop through and read all lines of, then add all of the substrings together for one final number.  The problem is, what I have is reading correctly and producing the number for the first line in the file only.  I'm not sure whether to use 'while' or 'for each'.  Here is the code I have:

```
    string filePath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["benefitsFile"];
    StreamReader reader = null;
    FileStream fs = null;
    try
    {
        //Read file and get estimated return.
        fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        reader = new StreamReader(fs);
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        int soldToDate = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(line.Substring(10, 15)));
        int currentReturn = Convert.ToInt32(soldToDate * .225);

        //Update the return amount
        updateCurrentReturn(currentReturn);
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: While (reader.ReadLine()) { }

Comment: string[] words = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);

Answer (score 4):

You use a while loop to do so, reading in each line and checking to see that it [hasn't returned null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx)

```
    string filePath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["benefitsFile"];
    StreamReader reader = null;
    FileStream fs = null;
    try
    {
        //Read file and get estimated return.
        fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        reader = new StreamReader(fs);

        string line;
        int currentReturn = 0;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null){
            int soldToDate = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(line.Substring(10, 15)));
            currentReturn += Convert.ToInt32(soldToDate * .225);
        }

        //Update the return amount
        updateCurrentReturn(currentReturn);

    }
    catch (IOException e){
     // handle exception and/or rethrow
    }
```

Comment: I believe the OP is looking for the sum of all lines, in which case `int currentReturn += Convert.ToInt32...` would do the trick.

Comment: Kyle, I am looking for the sum of all lines.  I ran the code in David N's answer above, and while the code seemed to run, my log file returned that the input string was not in a correct format at line 26, which is the 'int soldToDate' line...

Comment: I'm still getting the "input in an incorrect format" error at the int soldToDate line.  My format for each line is as such -

0000010004000000000000.00000000000000.00000000000000.00
0000010010000000037462.25000000021645.00000000005228.00
0000010015000000027240.00000000017072.00000000002259.00

Where I'd like to disregard the first 10 characters, and read the next 15 (my substring.)  For some reason, it keeps erroring out.  I tried changing the substring to 10,12 to drop the decimal and trailing zeroes, but got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to just use `File.ReadLines`:

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(filepath))
{
    //do stuff with line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a lot more universal since it works for most pieces of text.

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("file directory");
foreach(string line in text.Split('\n'))
{

}
```

Comment: Why waste all of the memory reading in the entire file when you can use `ReadLines` to stream it.  Beyond that, you also avoid needing to split the text, thus improving performance, and ensuring the operation will work even on operating systems with a new line other than `\n`.